# Replace end parenthesis in string with backslash character followed by end parenthesis

Tags: javascript, express

```
myString = 'he)llo)';

desiredString --> 'he\)llo\)';
```

I tried to use

```
var desiredString = myString.replace(')', '\\)');
```

But the resulting value for desiredString is then `'he)llo)'`

How can I get the `desiredString` value shown in the second line above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```js
var myString = 'he)llo)';
var desiredString = myString.replace(/\)/g, '\\\)');
console.log(desiredString);
```

`/\)/g` is a global regex for all occurrences of `)`. Normally it would just be `/<string to replace>/g`, however we need to use a `\` to escape the `)`.

For example:

```
"my string is my favorite".replace(/my/g, "your");
//your string is your favorite
```